# How to ignore {} in json path query

Tags: json, jmeter, jsonpath, vugen

I have json response (given below), from which I'm trying to extract availtimeSlots (each record). My Json path giving the output as **{"Sq.Num":"1","elapseTimeHour":"13","elapseTimeMinute":"30"}**(for first match). but I want to extract **"Sq.Num":"1","elapseTimeHour":"13","elapseTimeMinute":"30"** (don't want those {} to be included).
Json Path Expression: $.fa.availtimeSlots[*]

Json Body:

{"success":true,"fa":{"availtimeSlots":[{"Sq.Num":"1","elapseTimeHour":"13","elapseTimeMinute":"30"},{"Sq.Num":"2","elapseTimeHour":"22","elapseTimeMinute":"05"},{"Sq.Num":"3","elapseTimeHour":"13","elapseTimeMinute":"30"}]}}

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) somewhere **after** the JSON Extractor and use the following code:

```
1.upto(vars.get('myVar_matchNr') as int, {
    vars.put('myVar_' + it, vars.get('myVar_' + it).replace('{', '').replace('}', ''))
})
```

just replace `myVar` with what you set as the "Names of created variables" in the JSON Extractor and it will remove the curly braces from the extracted values.

In the above code snippet `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see
[Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information on this and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for the JSR223 Test Elements .

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what if this is load runner case?